# How do I enlarge a scaled image while still keeping its size?

Tags: java, image-processing, neural-network

I have a neural network (made in java) which classifies handwritten digits, trained using the mnist data set.

I have a GUI where the user will draw a number (number on the left) and when the user hits the "guess" button the drawing is converted into a 400 by 470 image and is down-scaled to a 20 by 20 image, then is centered to a 28 by 28 image to feed into the network where the output is given on the right.

Here is what the GUI looks like:
[image: GUI]

My problem however, is that when I have a number that doesn't take up the majority of the panel (such as the 3 in the image above) the down-scaled image that is used as the input for the network is too small which causes the network to guess incorrectly.

Here is the final input image when the number is drawn small:
[image: Small]

Here is the final input image when the number is drawn large:
[image: Large]

What I'm asking is: is there any way to make the number that is drawn small the  same size as the number drawn large while still keeping the size of the image as 28 by 28?

Comment: Opencv may be able to help; you could identify a rectangle that make covers the white pixels, from their you could scale it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use another object-detection network just to find the bounding box, or just calculate where the leftmost, rightmost, upmost, and bottom-most drawn pixel is. If you fear there will be outliers (there should not unless the user purposefully clicks an area far from the figure), you can remove outliers fairly easily. There are a number of ways, but method is to compute the distance of each drawn pixel to the center of the image, putting them into a distribution (normal might be good enough), and then compute which are outliers, and get rid of them. (Or compute the distance beyond which pixels become outliers, and cropping the box to fit). Then you scale the rectangle up to the correct size.

This is just a general method. As for specifics, I do not know how exactly your images are represented, but you can iterate over every pixel and note their positions (the number of iterations is not overly expensive).

Comment: morphological operators can help to get rid of small disconnected patches (aka outliers)